# Pandas: Stream real-time data -> Make a sample copy -> process data

Tags: python, pandas, real-time, quantitative-finance

I have a websocket feed coming from a cryptocurrency exchange of all current real-time trades as they happen (tick data). I want to store (only the last 5-10 minutes is necessary) and manipulate this data in real-time (every 5seconds) to then pass it to other functions.

Each tick looks like the below:

```
[{'homeNotional': 0.00546742, 'foreignNotional': 49, 'trdMatchID': '61c7a96f-28f3-0df1-4223-516d695333ee', 'tickDirection': 'ZeroMinusTick', 'price': 8962, 'timestamp': '2018-03-20T22:15:27.437Z', 'side': 'Sell', 'grossValue': 546742, 'size': 49, 'symbol': 'XBTUSD'}]
```

Which can then produce something like the below:

```
    foreignNotional grossValue  homeNotional    price   side    size    symbol  tickDirection              timestamp    trdMatchID
0   2                  22316    0.000223       8962.5   Buy        2    XBTUSD  PlusTick    2018-03-20T22:15:01.614Z    a06f6302-34b8-d307-e8e6-e4e617cbedf7
0   20                 223160   0.002232       8962.0   Sell      20    XBTUSD  MinusTick   2018-03-20T22:15:01.753Z    bb68d1f9-60ff-2990-c32a-bdbd14f5d773
0   22                 245476   0.002455       8962.5   Buy       22    XBTUSD  PlusTick    2018-03-20T22:15:01.858Z    a8e69797-5940-4aa1-2ab1-dd1ccceaa181
1   65                 725270   0.007253       8962.5   Buy       65    XBTUSD  ZeroPlusTick2018-03-20T22:15:01.858Z    685851cb-fd50-583d-5895-c91bbed10c98
```

My current idea is:

```
1. Append all tick data to df1 in real time
2. Take last 5 minutes of data from df1 and save it to df2
3. Run pre-processing on df2 including converting to OHLCV values and save in df3
4. Clear df2
5. Clear old cache of df1 every 10 minutes as I can't store it all in memory
6. Run steps 2,3&4 every 5 seconds.
```

**My questions are:**

Is this approach feasible and is pandas best suited for the task?

I'm currently using Jupyter notebooks and if I run step 1 and append my data to df1 I can't run concurrent tasks such as taking a slice and saving to df2. What is the best way around that?

Comment: May want to do three separate pieces:  wrap the socket with your own async client/server that outputs the chunks/format,  async functions for logic/processing, and storage/retention running in an event loop.

Comment: Wow ok, so this is not as straight-forward as I thought and out of my comfort zone as a hobbyist. So basically I should use `asyncio` to run each process? Any links for further reading is much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: check the [streamz](https://github.com/mrocklin/streamz) package, I think you should be able to use it to implement this relatively easily